# Create a function to color a cell on click according to column

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to Javascript and currently working on a school project in which I have 2 tables: one is a ranking table, and the other is a football matches table, all created by manipulating the DOM (we aren't allowed to use the HTML document to do anything but the creation of an anchor element in this task).

Whenever I click on a cell in the "wins" columns of the matches table, its background has to turn green. Meanwhile, in the ranking table, the click event has to add one victory and 3 points for the house team of that respective match, and 1 loss for the visitor team.
If there's a tie, the cell in the "Ties" column has to be colored yellow, and should the house team lose, the cell in the "Losses" column has to be colored red.
If I click again in the cell that has been colored, it should return to the previous state, as well as subtract the wins, points and losses that have been added to the ranking table.

I was able to come up with a brute force solution, which is not pretty and is far from ideal, and anyone can see that this become easily unusable should the table become longer. What I wanted to know is if there's a way to use a loop to make this code shorter, instead of having to identify each and every cell, which was the only way I could figure out how to color the background of the cell in the matches table and update the ranking table accordingly.

```
(() => {

    let rankingList = [
        { Team: "Team A", Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 },
        { Team: "Team B", Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 },
        { Team: "Team C", Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 },
        { Team: "Team D", Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 }
    ];

    let matchesList = [
        { House: "Team A", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team B' },
        { House: "Team C", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' },
        { House: "Team A", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' },
        { House: "Team B", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' },
        { House: "Team A", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' },
        { House: "Team B", Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' }
    ];


    function createTableHeading(table, text) {
        let header = table.createTHead();
        let line = header.insertRow();
        for (let index of text) {
            let th = document.createElement("th");
            let content = document.createTextNode(index);
            th.appendChild(content);
            line.appendChild(th);
            line.style = 'text-align: center;'
        }
    }

    function createTableBody(table, text) {
        for (let element of text) {
            let line = table.insertRow();
            for (index in element) {
                let cell = line.insertCell();
                let content = document.createTextNode(element[index]);

                cell.appendChild(content);
                cell.style = 'text-align: center;'
            }
        }
    }

    let $at = document.querySelector('#at'); // anchor element for HTML

    let $rankingTable = document.createElement('table');
    $rankingTable.id = 'ranking';
    $rankingTable.className = 'table';

    let $matchesTable = document.createElement('table');
    $matchesTable.id = 'matches';
    $matchesTable.className = 'table';

    $at.append($rankingTable);
    $at.append($matchesTable);
    let rankingText = Object.keys(rankingList[0]);
    let matchesText = Object.keys(matchesList[0]);
    createTableHeading($rankingTable, rankingText);
    createTableBody($rankingTable, rankingList);
    createTableHeading($matchesTable, matchesText);
    createTableBody($matchesTable, matchesList);

    let pointsA = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[1].cells[1];
    let pointsB = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[2].cells[1];
    let pointsC = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[3].cells[1];
    let pointsD = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[4].cells[1];

    let victoryA = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[1].cells[2];
    let victoryB = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[2].cells[2];
    let victoryC = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[3].cells[2];
    let victoryD = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[4].cells[2];
    
    let tieA = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[1].cells[3];
    let tieB = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[2].cells[3];
    let tieC = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[3].cells[3];
    let tieD = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[4].cells[3];

    let lossA = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[1].cells[4];
    let lossB = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[2].cells[4];
    let lossC = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[3].cells[4];
    let lossD = document.getElementById('ranking').rows[4].cells[4];

    // Team A x Team B
    let cell1 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[1].cells[1];
    let cell2 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[1].cells[2];
    let cell3 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[1].cells[3];

    // Team C x Team D

    let cell4 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[2].cells[1];
    let cell5 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[2].cells[2];
    let cell6 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[2].cells[3];

    // Team A x Team C

    let cell7 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[3].cells[1];
    let cell8 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[3].cells[2];
    let cell9 = document.getElementById('matches').rows[3].cells[3];

    cell1.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor);
    cell2.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor2);
    cell3.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor3);
    cell4.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor4);
    cell5.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor5);
    cell6.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor6);
    cell7.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor7);
    cell8.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor8);
    cell9.addEventListener("click", setBackgroundColor9);

    function updateTableVictory(pointsTeam1, victoryTeam1, lossTeam2,i,j){
        rankingList[i].Wins += 1;
        rankingList[j].Losses += 1;
        rankingList[i].Points += 3; 
        
        pointsTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Points;
        victoryTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Wins;
        lossTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Losses;
    }

    function updateTableTie(pointsTeam1, tieTeam1, pointsTeam2, tieTeam2, i,j){
        rankingList[i].Ties += 1;
        rankingList[j].Ties += 1;
        rankingList[i].Points += 1;
        rankingList[j].Points += 1;
        pointsTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Points;
        tieTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Ties;
        pointsTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Points;
        tieTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Ties;
    }

    function updateTableLoss(pointsTeam2, victoryTeam2, lossTeam1,i,j){
        rankingList[i].Losses += 1;
        rankingList[j].Wins += 1;
        rankingList[j].Points += 3; 

        pointsTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Points;
        victoryTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Wins;
        lossTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Losses;
    }

    function resetTableWin(pointsTeam1, victoryTeam1, lossTeam2,i,j){
        rankingList[i].Wins -= 1;
        rankingList[j].Losses -= 1;
        rankingList[i].Points -= 3; 
        
        pointsTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Points;
        victoryTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Wins;
        lossTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Losses;
    }

    function resetTableTie(pointsTeam1, tieTeam1, pointsTeam2, tieTeam2, i,j){
        rankingList[i].Ties -= 1;
        rankingList[j].Ties -= 1;
        rankingList[i].Points -= 1;
        rankingList[j].Points -= 1;
        pointsTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Points;
        tieTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Ties;
        pointsTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Points;
        tieTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Ties;
    }

    function resetTableLoss(pointsTeam2, victoryTeam2, lossTeam1,i,j){
        rankingList[i].Losses -= 1;
        rankingList[j].Wins -= 1;
        rankingList[j].Points -= 3; 

        pointsTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Points;
        victoryTeam2.innerText = rankingList[j].Wins;
        lossTeam1.innerText = rankingList[i].Losses;
    }

    // Team A x Team B

    // Victory

    function setBackgroundColor() {
        if(cell1.style.backgroundColor){
            cell1.style.backgroundColor = '';
            resetTableWin(pointsA,victoryA,lossB,0,1)
        } else {
            cell1.style.backgroundColor = '#85e085';
            updateTableVictory(pointsA,victoryA,lossB,0,1);
        }
    }

    // Tie

    function setBackgroundColor2() {
        if(cell2.style.backgroundColor){
            cell2.style.backgroundColor = ''
            resetTableTie(pointsA, tieA, pointsB, tieB,0,1);
        } else {
            cell2.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe066';
            updateTableTie(pointsA, tieA, pointsB, tieB,0,1);
        }
    }

    // Loss

    function setBackgroundColor3() {
        if(cell3.style.backgroundColor){
            cell3.style.backgroundColor = '';
            resetTableLoss(pointsB,victoryB,lossA,0,1)
        } else {
            cell3.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4d4d';
            updateTableLoss(pointsB,victoryB,lossA,0,1);
        }
    }

    // Team C x Team D

    // Victory 

    function setBackgroundColor4() {
        cell4.style.backgroundColor = '#85e085';
        updateTableVictory(pointsC,victoryC,lossD,2,3);
    }

    // Tie

    function setBackgroundColor5() {
        cell5.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe066';
        updateTableTie(pointsC,tieC,pointsD,tieD,2,3);
    }

    // Loss

    function setBackgroundColor6() {
        cell6.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4d4d';
        updateTableLoss(pointsD,victoryD,lossC,2,3);
    }

    // Team A x Team C

    // Victory

    function setBackgroundColor7() {
        cell7.style.backgroundColor = '#85e085';
        updateTableVictory(pointsA,victoryA,lossC,0,2);
    }

    // Tie

    function setBackgroundColor8() {
        cell8.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe066';
        updateTableTie(pointsA,tieA,pointsC,tieC,0,2);
    }

    // Loss

    function setBackgroundColor9() {
        cell9.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4d4d';
        updateTableLoss(pointsC,victoryC,lossA,0,2);
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question titillated me a little, I could not help but seek a complete solution.

but when I wanted to add it here to replace my previous solution, its validation on SO was rejected.

So I added it here

```js
// utilities ---------------
HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.addCell = function(...argN)
  {
  let tag = argN.includes('th') ? 'th' : 'td'
    , elm = this.appendChild( document.createElement(tag) )
    ;
  for(let arg of argN) 
    {
    if ( typeof(arg)==='string' && !['th','td'].includes(arg) )
      elm.textContent = arg
    else if (typeof(arg)==='object')
      for (let attr in arg  )
        elm.setAttribute( attr, arg[attr] )
    }
  return elm
  }
// -------------------- utilities end 
const
  $at = document.querySelector('#at')  
, rankingList = 
  [ { Team: 'Team A', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team B', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team C', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team D', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  ] 
, matchesList = 
  [ { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team B' } 
  , { House: 'Team C', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' } 
  , { House: 'Team B', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team B', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' } 
  ]
, clickAction =
  { Win  : { House : { Points: 3, Wins: 1, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 }, Visitor: { Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 1 } }
  , Tie  : { House : { Points: 1, Wins: 0, Ties: 1, Losses: 0 }, Visitor: { Points: 1, Wins: 0, Ties: 1, Losses: 0 } }
  , Loss : { House : { Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 1 }, Visitor: { Points: 3, Wins: 1, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } }
  }
, rankCols    = Object.keys( clickAction.Win.House )
, clickable   = Object.keys( clickAction )
  ;

function tableMaker(id, jsObj,ref)
  {
  let cols  = Object.keys(jsObj[0])
    , tab   = ref.appendChild( document.createElement('table'))
    , tHead = tab.createTHead()
    , tBody = tab.createTBody()
    , rowX  = tHead.insertRow()
    ;
  tab.id = id
  cols.forEach(col=> rowX.addCell('th', col) )
  jsObj.forEach((o,idx)=>
    {
    rowX = tBody.insertRow()
    rowX.dataset.index = idx
    cols.forEach(col=>
      {
      let isClikable = clickable.includes(col)
        , cls = isClikable ? { class:'clickable' } : {}
        ;
      rowX.addCell(cls).textContent = o[col]
      if (isClikable && o[col] === 'x' )
        rowX.className = col
      })
    })
  return tab
  }
const 
  t_Ranking = tableMaker('ranking', rankingList, $at)
, t_Matches = tableMaker('matches', matchesList, $at) 
  ;
t_Matches.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('td.clickable')) return // ignore click elsewhere
  
  let row               = target.closest('tr')
    , row_index         = parseInt(row.dataset.index)
    , colNth            = target.cellIndex +1
    , colName           = t_Matches.querySelector(`thead > tr > th:nth-of-type(${colNth})`).textContent
    , HouseTeam         = row.querySelector(`td:nth-of-type(1)`).textContent
    , VisitorTeam       = row.querySelector(`td:nth-of-type(5)`).textContent
    , rowClass          = row.className ?? ''
    , rankingHouseIdx   = rankingList.findIndex(x=>x.Team === HouseTeam)
    , rankingVisitorIdx = rankingList.findIndex(x=>x.Team === VisitorTeam)
    , rankingHouse      = rankingList[ rankingHouseIdx ]
    , rankingVisitor    = rankingList[ rankingVisitorIdx ]
    ;
  if (rowClass != '')
    {
    for (let score in clickAction[rowClass].House)   rankingHouse[score]   -= clickAction[rowClass].House[score]
    for (let score in clickAction[rowClass].Visitor) rankingVisitor[score] -= clickAction[rowClass].Visitor[score]
    row.className = ''
    matchesList[row_index][rowClass] = ''
    }
  if (rowClass != colName)
    {
    for (let score in clickAction[colName].House)   rankingHouse[score]   += clickAction[colName].House[score]
    for (let score in clickAction[colName].Visitor) rankingVisitor[score] += clickAction[colName].Visitor[score]
    row.className = colName
    matchesList[row_index][colName] = 'x'
    }


  let tr_RankingHouse   = t_Ranking.querySelector(`tbody > tr[data-index="${rankingHouseIdx}"]`)
    , tr_RankingVisitor = t_Ranking.querySelector(`tbody > tr[data-index="${rankingVisitorIdx}"]`)

  // DOM IHM part  

  rankCols.forEach((nam,idx)=> tr_RankingHouse.cells[idx+1].textContent   = rankingHouse[nam]   )  
  rankCols.forEach((nam,idx)=> tr_RankingVisitor.cells[idx+1].textContent = rankingVisitor[nam] )  

  clickable.forEach((nam,idx)=> row.cells[idx+1].textContent = matchesList[row_index][nam] ) 
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  text-align : center;
  }
td.clickable {
  cursor     : pointer;
  color      : transparent;
  min-width  : 2.8em;
  }
thead                     { background-color : lightseagreen; }
tbody > tr:hover          { background-color : lightcyan; }
tr.Win  td:nth-of-type(2) { background-color : #85e085; }
tr.Tie  td:nth-of-type(3) { background-color : #ffe066; }
tr.Loss td:nth-of-type(4) { background-color : #ff4d4d; }
```

```html
<div id="at"></div>
```

Comment: Hey there! Many thanks for your contribution and for taking the time to help! Works like a charm! I'll read the documentation so I can understand a bit better some parts of it, but really, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

do something like that...
*PS:* [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)

```js
const
  $at = document.querySelector('#at')  
, rankingList = 
  [ { Team: 'Team A', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team B', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team C', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  , { Team: 'Team D', Points: 0, Wins: 0, Ties: 0, Losses: 0 } 
  ] 
, matchesList = 
  [ { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team B' } 
  , { House: 'Team C', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' } 
  , { House: 'Team B', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team A', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team D' } 
  , { House: 'Team B', Win: '', Tie: '', Loss: '', Visitor: 'Team C' } 
  ];

function tableMaker(id, jsObj,ref)
  {
  let cols  = Object.keys(jsObj[0])
    , tab   = ref.appendChild( document.createElement('table'))
    , tHead = tab.createTHead()
    , tBody = tab.createTBody()
    , rowX  = tHead.insertRow()
    ;
  tab.id = id
  cols.forEach(col=> rowX.insertCell().textContent = col )
  jsObj.forEach(o=>
    {
    rowX = tBody.insertRow()
    cols.forEach(col=> rowX.insertCell().textContent = o[col] )
    })
  return tab
  }

const wTables =
  [ { tRef : tableMaker('ranking', rankingList, $at) , col  : -1 }
  , { tRef : tableMaker('matches', matchesList, $at) , col  : -1 }
  ]
wTables.forEach(wt=>
  {
  wt.tRef.onclick = ({target}) =>
    {
    if (!target.matches('thead td')) return // ignore click
    let colN = target.cellIndex +1
    if ( wt.tRef.col > 0 )
      wt.tRef.querySelectorAll(`tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(${wt.tRef.col})`).forEach(td=>td.classList.remove('colSelected'))
    if ( wt.tRef.col != colN )
      {
      wt.tRef.col = colN
      wt.tRef.querySelectorAll(`tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(${wt.tRef.col})`).forEach(td=>td.classList.add('colSelected'))
      }
    else wt.tRef.col = -1
    }
  })
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead {
  background : lightseagreen ;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
td.colSelected {
  background-color : lightcyan;
  }
```

```html
<div id="at"></div>
```